# cider-nrepl error when running project

Tags: clojure, leiningen, cider, nrepl

I try running lein project with `cider/cider-nrepl`.

I write `[cider/cider-nrepl "0.10.1"]` in `plugins` section of `project.clj`

After running `cider-jack-in`
i have error - `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve var:    cider.nrepl.middleware.apropos/wrap-apropos in this context`

If i remove cider plugin from `project.clj` Cider run fine, but M-., `cider-jump-to-var` function not work.

**update**

i created new minimal lein app:

`$lein deps :tree`

```
[clojure-complete "0.2.3" :scope "test" :exclusions   [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
 [org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
 [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.6" :scope "test" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
```

project.clj

```
(defproject app "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]])
```

`$lein version`

```
Leiningen 2.5.1 on Java 1.8.0_72-internal OpenJDK Server VM
```

i have a custom `profile.clj` for lein.

```
{:repl {:dependencies [[org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.12"]]}}
```

Comment: can you include your `project.clj` and the full stacktrace?

Comment: could you include the output of running "lein deps :tree"

Comment: it seems after creating custom profles.clj for lein all works.

Answer (score 4):

Problems like this are often caused by different dependencies, either plugin or otherwise, requiring different versions of the same library. The best way to sort it out is to run:

```
lein deps :tree
```

and look at all the lines that suggest exclusions. There is a good chance that it's printing a warning about multiple dependencies resolving different versions of nrepl or one of it's dependencies. If that does not lead to an obvious conflict then try, **making a blank project with `lein new app` and then get cider working there, in isolation**, before moving it back into your main project.